# Extract minute wise data in R

Tags: r

with the help of below code, I am able to get stocks information on a daily basis. But is there a way to get it on a minute basis. Please help

```
symbols <- c("GODREJIND.NS", "ASHOKLEY.NS")
sd <- as.Date("2019-10-25")
ed <- as.Date("2019-10-31")


tq_get(symbols, 
       from = sd, 
       to = ed )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data if date is "YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS" format then you can extract minutewise data using below code.

```
df$MINUTES_sd <- minutes(df$sd)
df$MINUTES_ed <- minutes(df$ed)
```

Similarly you can extract year,month,day,hour from data to further analysis of your data set.
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(symbol=c("GODREJIND.NS", "ASHOKLEY.NS"),sd="2019-10- 
25",ed='2019-10-31')

df$YEAR_sd <- year(df$sd)
df$MONTH_sd <- month(df$sd)
df$DAY_sd <- day(df$sd)

df$YEAR_ed <- year(df$ed)
df$MONTH_ed <- month(df$ed)
df$DAY_ed <- day(df$ed)
```

Comment: May I know what is df here. I tried actually, But not getting

Comment: df means your data frame

Comment: Nope. It is not working. I tried. However the date is not in YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS" format